# Entity Frame work Coded first - Create Readonly EDMX Model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am just starting out with EF Code-first:

If I create a read-only EDMX file from my code first can I save this readonly file as a stand-alone file and then include the resultant file in my project without affecting code first implementation.

Even though I am doing code first, I like a picture as it helps when I am explaining the db model to others.  But I do not want to included this if it effects the code-first approach

will adding the EDMX file to the code-first project cause problems with the code-first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't have any effect on your code First approach. You can add the .edmx file directly to your project from Add-> New Item and generate the model from database without affecting your code-first approach. Just remember to use different namespaces so you don't get namespace conflict between your code-first and model classes.

To remove the Model, just remember to delete the related connection string in app.config/web.config to prevent your config files from becoming messy.

Comment: Thank you I had hoped as much.